# Existence and uniqueness of heteroclinic orbits

Tags: ds.dynamical-systems, existence-theorems

I am looking for conditions on a nonlinear dynamical system $\frac{d\vec{x}}{dt} = \vec{F}(\vec{x})$ that guarantee the existence of a unique heteroclinic orbit between a stable attractor of this system and an unstable fixed point on the boundary of the basin of attraction of that attractor.  Such conditions could be as strong as needing to be a smooth gradient dynamical system ($\frac{d\vec{x}}{dt} = - \nabla V(\vec{x})$, where $V(\vec{x})$ is smooth), for example, but ideally would be as general as possible.

Comment: How do you know the unstable fixed point is on the boundary of the basin? Whatever provides this knowledge is almost sure to be useful.

Comment: I see what you are getting at, I think (looking at the linearization of the system around this point and following the unstable manifold), but I was looking for a more general result. I found in the the theory of monotone systems, although these are quite constrained.

Comment: Usually one can find heteroclinic orbits for these systems as minimum length connecting curves for the Jacobi metric, suitably reparametrized.

Comment: In response to the question, it turns out I was looking for the local invariant manifold theorem. Thanks for the responses.